# What does word "acc :" means in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have homework where I need to explain word "acc::", but I can't find it anywhere, need help?

I have read the Scala Standard Library from https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/index.html but still could not find it. I have also read the ebook of Scala https://underscore.io/training/courses/essential-scala/ but still could not find it.

`(n::acc.head) :: acc.tail`

`case (n, ( _  ,acc)) => (n, List(n) :: acc)`

Is this just a variable or something else?

Comment: I guess it means "accumulator". It looks like you collect something into the list.

Answer (score 1):

`acc` is not a reserved word in Scala, in your code it seems to be a val that represents an accumulator (it looks like a `List`)

In Scala you can build a `List` by using the `::` operator putting the head of the list at the left and the tail at the right like this

`1 :: 2 :: Nil // List(1, 2)`
if you already have a list acc you can add an element by doing

`1 :: acc`

Comment: Care to expand a bit ? The question asks for `acc::`, not just `acc`

Comment: I have added some information about `::` that is a method of `List`

Comment: for more information about `List` read this https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-list-class-examples

Comment: Thank you sir, for the answer

Comment: can you accept the answer if it resolve your question? thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your first example there will be a variable or argument called `acc` somewhere in scope.

In your second example, `acc` is a new variable declared as part of the `match`.

If you have a value like this

```
val x = (5, (0, 1))
```

and a match like this

```
x match {
  case (n, (_ ,acc)) => (n, List(n) :: acc)
}
```

then in the code after the `=>`,  `n` will be `5` and `acc` will be `1`. So the result of this expression will be `(5, List(5, 1))`

The `0` value is not captured because the match value is `_`.

Comment: Thank you sir, for the answer